# How do you call a singleton class method from Objective C in a Swift class?

Tags: objective-c, swift, singleton, class-method

I have the following objective C code which I need to get into a Swift class :

In Logger.m -

```
+ (Logger *) log
{
static Logger *sharedLog = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedLogger = [[self alloc] init];
});

return sharedLogger;
}

- (void) printString:(NSString *) s
{
    NSLog(s)
}
```

Which is in Logger.h as -

```
+ (Logger *) log;
- (void) printString:(NSString *) s;
```

Now, I have this code bridged in to Swift Project - LoggerUserApp where I'm trying to use the above print method from the singleton `log` shared class method.

I've tried -

```
Logger.log().printString("String")  // Compiler Error. Use Object Construction Logger()
Logger().log().printString("String")  // Compiler Error. 
Logger().log.printString("String") // Compiler Error. 
Logger.printString("String") // This does not call log
```

Can someone tell me what might be going wrong?

Comment: why is this question down voted ?  It looks proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Swift update, if the class method's name is similar to the class name, then it just takes that as a custom initializer. Now since there was no parameter in the method, it wouldn't come up as the default initializer would come up instead.

Hence, to solve this problem, I had to change the name of the class method `log` to something different like `newLog`... and it worked fine.

```
Logger.newLog().printString("")
```

Comment: Your (current version of the) question does not mention any `PALog` class or any  `external:` parameter, so it is unclear what your answer refers to. For future readers it would be helpful if you update either the question or the answer so that they match each other.

Comment: Sorry for that. I corrected it. Could you please remove the downvote now?

I'm actually updating the answer now. Turns out there is a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the Swift compiler mistakenly identifies a method as a class factory method, you can use the NS_SWIFT_NAME macro, passing the Swift signature of the method to have it imported correctly. For example:

```
+ (id)recordWithQuality:(double)quality NS_SWIFT_NAME(record(quality:));
```

so,your method should be this:

```
+ (Logger *) log NS_SWIFT_NAME(log());
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your example completely, but at first sight, this should work:

```
Logger.log().printString("String")
```

Since your Obj-C singleton is a *function* returning the singleton (hence `Logger.log()` will return your singleton.

But since in your example code I see `Logger` and then `PALog` I can't say if this is all you need.

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed it to use Logger. BTW.. the `Logger` is coming to `LoggerUserApp` as a Pod.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other errors in your example: `sharedLog` and than `sharedLogger`.
Here is an example that should work:

Logger.h

```
@interface Logger : NSObject

+ (Logger *) log;
- (void) printString:(NSString *) s;

@end
```

Logger.m

```
#import "Logger.h"

@implementation Logger

+ (Logger *) log
{
    static Logger *sharedLog = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedLog = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedLog;
}

- (void) printString:(NSString *) s
{
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}

@end
```

...-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "Logger.h"
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Logger.log().printString("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to call this using this way. I'm using the latest XCode and Swift update. could you confirm you're doing the same?

Comment: Yes. Started from a single view empty project in Swift. Latest public Xcode release. (no beta)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I upvoted your answers. But it looks like the compiler was already giving me the answer.